# How was the design of active filter topologies arrived at, invented or discovered?

Tags: design, active-filter

Active filters make use of Op-Amps. This can make it possible to avoid using inductors and get the same effect by "reversing" a capacitor. There are multiple topologies in existance for these active filters:

```
Chebyshev filter
Butterworth filter
Bessel filter
Elliptic filter
```

I can see that they have different role off and amount of ripples in pass band and stop band. What I do not understand is how these were discovered or invented in the first place. I fully understand passive filters made up of RLC. It is evident how they work and why they are the way they are. However, for the active filters it is not clear. Did the designers get a hypethetical transfer function first and then realize it in electronics?

Comment: They were scaled from the original passive versions of the same filters. Which just passes the buck... how were THOSE generated? Here's one interesting tid-bit : Professor Chebyshev made his name back in the steam engine days : he invented a "link motion" which translated rotary motion into an equi-ripple 6th order approximation to a straight line. An important trick for steam machine designers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_linkage (James Watt famously invented a 5th order approximation - his "parallel link motion" over a century earlier)

Answer (score 8):

A filter topology, whether it's a passive one like a pi-section or an active one like the Sallen-Key circuit, is just a way to produce some poles and zeros. Generally, you can tune the circuit values (resistances, capacitances, inductances) to move those poles and zeros around in the *s*-plane.

A filter design, like Butterworth or Chebychev, is a choice of pole and zero locations that gives a certain performance (Butterworth has maximally flat pass-band, and Chebychev filters minimize the error between the real filter and a boxcar filter, for example).

You can use whatever filter topology you like to implement whichever filter design you like. First determine the desired pole and zero locations from the filter design. Then tune your component values to achieve those locations. However, you might find that some topologies require unreasonably large or small component values for certain filter designs, or be excessively sensitive to errors in the component values, and that kind of issue might motivate you to use a different topology.

As to how they were invented, I suspect the guys who came up with them were simply very very clever.

Answer (score 6):

Quantum231 - I do not fully understand what you really want, because:

- The four types you have listed are NOT different filter topologies (functions) - instead, they are 4 different approximations to an IDEAL lowpass response (and they can be transferred to corresponding highpass and bandpass approximations);
- All these filter functions can be realized applying one of the various topologies (active or passive); for example, for 2nd-order lowpass realizations there are more than 15 different topologies.

So my question to you is: Are you looking for explantions regarding topologies (circuit alternatives) or approximation methods (as listed by you)?

Nevertheless, here are some informations regarding filter realization (2nd order):

- Sallen-Key structure (single feedback): Based on a simple RC lowpass (1st order) we have simple second-order form using two such sections in series - however, with a poor damping behaviour (only real poles). Now, the pole-Q can be enhanced drastically using positive feedback. From system theory we know that positive feedback shifts the poles to the imag. axis. Hence, one of the grounded capacitors is lifted and connected to the output of a positive-gain stage.
- Multi-feedback structure: From system theory we know that zeros in the feedback network are transferred to poles of the closed-loop gain function. Since a long time it is known that the classical bridged T-network is able to produce conjugate-complex zeros. Therefore, using such a network as feedback path gives us a circuit with conjugate-complex poles (what was our goal).
- Three opamp integrator topologies (universal filter): These structures can be easily derived from the differential equation (time domain). This procedure is based on the classical diff. equation for damped mechanical oscillations. This equation can be transferred to an integral equation - and this equation then is hardware-realized by integrating blocks. During this procedure, we have some alternatives (inverting or non-inverting integrator blocks) leading to the three major integrator filters: KHN, Tow-Thomas or Fleischer-Tow.
- Another important structure is based on impedance converters. This is an active circuit (one or two opamps) which can mimic a grounded inductance. This is a very versatile technique because we can replace inductors with an active circuit. This method allows us to actively realize a variety of classical passive ladder RLC structurs. These topologies have the best properties regarding tolerance sensitivity! 
  It is important to note that this technique allows us to actively realize higher order filter functions (n>2). This is called "direct realization" - in contrast to the first three methods which uses a cascade of 2nd-order sections if higher-order functions are required.

**UPDATE:**

- Perhaps you are interested to hear also about one of the most "genious" ideas: The **BRUTON transformation**. Based on the transfer function of one of the classical passive RLC ladder topologies we can divide each impedance (R, sL and 1/sC) by a dimensionless factor (s*T). Because this is done in the numerator and the denominator of the transfer function there is no change of the filter characteristic. However, the characteristic of each impedance has changed: From R to 1/sC" , from sL to R" and from 1/sC to s²D". 
  The values of the parts with (") depend on the time constant T which can be freely chosen. The new (artificial) part D" is called "frequency dependent negative resistor, FDNR" and can be realized with an impedance converter (similar to the inductance simulation mentioned in point 4.). As a result, we again have an active filter ciruit (of 2nd order or even higher) with excellent tolerance properties - without the necessity to use coils.

Answer (score 4):

Chebyshev, Butterworth, Bessel and Cauer (Elliptic) approximations are not strictly implemented as active filters. They can be made passive as well, with insertion loss, but that isn't relevant at the moment. All they are is transfer functions. For a given corner frequency, each approximation will have a slightly different transfer function, but their frequency response will all cross at the corner frequency. Each approximation has a known set of characteristics, and for a given circumstance, one may approximation may be more desirable than another. It's a complex subject, and gets mathy instantly. How their inventors arrived at the approximations is more history than electronics.